# adding almost sure convergence

Tags: probability

Say $x_n\rightarrow a$ a.s., $y_n\rightarrow b$ a.s., where a and b are constants.

Is there a theorem that says $x_n+y_n\rightarrow a+b$ a.s., in particular when $x_n$ and $y_n$ are not independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\pr}{\operatorname{Pr}}$Let $A\subseteq\Omega$ be the subspace on which $x_n(\omega)\to a(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in A$, and $B\subseteq\Omega$ the subspace on which $y_n(\omega)\to b(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in B$. Almost sure convergence means $\pr(\Omega\setminus A)=0=\pr(\Omega\setminus B)$.

$(x_n+y_n)(\omega)\to(a+b)(\omega)$ everywhere on $A\cap B$.

$$\pr(\Omega\setminus(A\cap B))=\pr((\Omega\setminus A)\cup(\Omega\setminus B))\le\Pr(\Omega\setminus A)+\Pr(\Omega\setminus B)=0$$

So yes, this convergence is almost sure.

Strictly speaking, $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily measurable - it is common to define "almost sure" or "almost everywhere" as $\Omega\setminus A$ is *contained in* a null set. The same proof applies.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Does the above proof also mean that a and b in my original question don't have to be constants?

Comment: @orangecat Yes, it holds for all random variables $a,b$. All you need is a notion of convergence in the codomains (e.g. it's usually $\Bbb R$ so that's fine)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this always holds. You can see this by considering $A:=\{\omega \in \Omega : x_n(\omega) \to a, y_n \to b \}$. Then, $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$ and for $\omega \in A$ you have
$$x_n(\omega)+y_n(\omega)\to a+b.$$ Since $A$ has probability $1$, you have almost sure convergence.